# Set Public Const using VBA from worksheet data

Tags: arrays, excel, constants, vba

I have a something in the order of 40 constants to declare as constants. i.e. 
Year Dept   Senior Manager Name (and each year it increases). The names are setup in a worksheet (Column A,B)

---

Column A        Column B
2016 PT-1   "PT-1-Snr Mgr Name 1"

2016 PT-2   "PT-2-Snr Mgr Name 2"

...

2016 PT-20  "PT-20-Snr Mgr Name 20"

---

2017 PT-1   "PT-1-Snr Mgr Name 21"

2017 PT-2   "PT-2-Snr Mgr Name 22"

...

2017 PT-20  PT-20-Snr Mgr Name 40

---

Through the loops of my VBA programming I want to tag each transaction (CSV line) with a "PT-1-Snr Mgr Name 1" in a separate column for use in a Tableau Dashboard as a filter. But the source data only has the Year and the Dept i.e. "2016 PT-1" so I need to lookup this name for millions of rows using VBA.

**I am aware how to set up : Public Const 2016_PT-1 = "Snr Mgr Name 1" etc but really need to do this with code from a worksheet.**

I have tried using vlookup from a worksheet or arrays but it is inefficient and is very slow.
I would think it is better to find a way to declare these as "Const" once and then when I get the source data perform a internal code lookup :

Lookup_string = Year & " " & Dept to get "**2016 PT-1**" and then use this to find the "**PT-1-Snr Mgr Name 1**"

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance : )

Comment: The value of a `Const` needs to be a compile-time constant expression. Therefore looking it up from a spreadsheet won't work. What you could do, though, is have a worksheet called `Constants` and then reference its values with e.g. `[Constants!A1]`. Alternatively, declare it in Name Manager.

Comment: Great thxs - I like the [Constants!A1] idea but this still means I have to find the relevant row which is the bit that takes processing time - hence slows it down. Might look at the named range. Just setup 40 odd named ranges and lookup the contents of that names range. i.e. "2016_PT_1" equates to "Snr Mgr Name 1" and so forth. Good way forward. Thank you for the seed.

Comment: User `Find` to find the relevant row - much faster than checking each cell. You could also pass them into a dictionary or collection object so you can reference them by name.

Comment: Sounds like you want an array, or better still a dictionary.